# Make img fluid HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with my image, when I resize my browser it's neither responding nor fluid.

I don't know what's wrong? I changed the width to 100% but it's still the same. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're setting fixed widths on `#wp_skitter` and `.container_skitter`. Remove those and you're good to go

Comment: @Bojangles where did you find #wp_skitter?

Comment: On the page you linked... It's a direct child of `#logo`. Is your link incorrect?

Comment: @Bojangles I found it but I changed it to 100% still the same?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of width:100%

try:

```
Max-width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have fixed width on `#wp_skitter`. To answer your comment, you will find inside
your header, inside the `#logo`